# Why I'm getting [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory?

Tags: mariadb

I run wordpress website on CentOS 7, RAM 8GB.

Mariadb returning "[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)" in my wordpress website.

```
[root@izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z /]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

What should I fine tune the my.cnf?

```
/etc/my.cnf

# The MariaDB server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir         = /tmp/

 [mysqldump]
 quick
 max_allowed_packet = 16M

 [mysql]
 no-auto-rehash
 # Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with 
 SQL
 #safe-updates

 [myisamchk]
 key_buffer_size = 20M
 sort_buffer_size = 20M
 read_buffer = 2M
 write_buffer = 2M

 [mysqlhotcopy]
 interactive-timeout
```

In here I add some mariadb.log info after I restarted it, hopefully this is enough for investigation.

```
/var/log/mariadb.log

230616 11:02:38 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
230616 11:02:38 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
230616 11:02:38  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
230616 11:02:39  InnoDB: Waiting for 9 pages to be flushed
230616 11:02:40  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 
5956557136
230616 11:02:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

230616 11:02:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file 
/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
230616 11:02:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases 
from /var/lib/mysql
230616 11:02:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.68-MariaDB) 
starting as process 7417 ...
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic 
builtins
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
230616 11:02:40 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
230616 11:02:40  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to 
start
230616 11:02:41 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61- 
MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 5956557136
230616 11:02:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
230616 11:02:42 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
230616 11:02:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
230616 11:02:42 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  
port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

I need advice, many thanks in advance.

Comment: What else is running on the machine? How much memory does everything else consume? I'm assuming the MariaDB is on its default innodb size causing this error at startup, but the limited logs make it hard to be sure.

Comment: the server acts as a web server, wordpress and apache run in there, I added some log info in my question.

Comment: Do you have a swap file configured on that machine?

Comment: No

[root@izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z mariadb]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         1929696        0   1929696   0% /dev
tmpfs            1940092       28   1940064   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1940092      488   1939604   1% /run
tmpfs            1940092        0   1940092   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1       41151808 14803488  24234888  38% /
tmpfs             388020        0    388020   0% /run/user/0